# Get total from amounts in rows MySQL PHP

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I'm working on a lottery system for my game and i'm having issues with the total pot size

current progress: http://playsilab.com/lottery

Anyways, what i'm doing is having it so a user will buy a ticket in the game and that will count as +5 currency to the pot.

This is what the table looks like
[image]

basically i need it to count all those 5000000's and output 1 number
or my other idea, get the amount of people and *5
any of those would be great :)

basically for 8 people with 5000000, it should print out 40000000 (40M)

my attempt:

```
$pot = mysql_query("SELECT name, SUM(pot), COUNT(name) FROM contestants");
$details = mysql_fetch_array($pot);
$totalpot = $details['SUM($details['pot']'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$totalpot = $details['SUM($details['pot']'];
```

The problem seems to be a combination of:

- unescaped quotes inside a quoted string
- your dollar reference is not being evaluated since it is inside single quotes
- a missing parenthesis
- and just generally not being correct

Give your columns aliases so that it is easier to refer to them in your source code:

```
SELECT SUM(pot) AS sum_pot, COUNT(name) AS count_name FROM contestants
```

Then you can just write:

```
$totalpot = $details['sum_pot'];
```

Also there are a number of other problems with your code, for example:

- You are not checking to see if you query failed before trying to access the results.
- It makes little sense to return both a `name` from a single row and an aggregated value like a `SUM` in the same result set. In MySQL it is legal, but in many other databases this would be rejected as an error.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
list($totalpot) = @mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(pot) FROM contestants WHERE pot=5000000"));
list($count) = @mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contestants WHERE pot=5000000"));
```

or if you want to have sums by pot amount

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pot, SUM(pot) as sum_pot, COUNT(*) as count_pot FROM contestants GROUP BY pot");
while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // $row['pot'] is 50000
    // $row['sum_pot'] is 40M
    // $row['count_pot'] is 8
}
```